# PL/SQL plugin for Eclipse

Tags: plsql, eclipse-plugin

I've been looking for git support for one of the PL/SQL ides that I already use. Maybe I should be looking for a PL/SQL plugin for Eclipse since excellent support for git is already there. Can anyone suggest a free plugin for Eclipse that's as good as PL/SQL support in JDeveloper? I've tried a few existing plugins but  most felt like toys compared with JDeveloper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [jOra](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jora-oracle-db-plugin) and [Toad](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/toad-extension-eclipse) in Eclipse marketplace.

Comment: from marketplace link: "jOra was (and for me still is) a great database plugin. But you **won't get it here anymore**. jOra is now the foundation for the new Toad Extension for Eclipse"